# Useful Resources for CS Educators (Index)

Tags: discussion, resource

This post is an experiment - it may disappear. It is also in process and will be updated frequently.

This is an index to other posts that detail useful resources of various kinds

- [Mailing Lists](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/297/1293)
- [Organizations](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/1293)
- [IDEs](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/299/1293)
- Blogs by/for educators

More (TBD)