# Mailing Lists for Educators

Tags: discussion, resource

This post is an experiment. It may disappear

Mailing lists for Educators

- [SIGCSE](http://sigcse.org/sigcse/membership/mailing-lists) SIGCSE members are subscribed to both an information distribution list and a discussion list.
- [APCS](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org) The College Board has a number of specialized lists for Advanced Placement CS teachers.
- [CSTA](http://www.csteachers.org) Members are subscribed to an information distribution list.

More (TBD)

Comment: Are there others?