# Organizations for CS Educators

Tags: discussion, resource

This post is an experiment. It may disappear

Organizations for Educators

- [SIGCSE](http://sigcse.org/sigcse/membership/mailing-lists) SIGCSE is the Special Interest Group for CS Educators within the ACM. Membership is inexpensive. SIGCSE and associated organizations hold many conferences each year.
- [APCS](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org) The College Board has a special interest group for Advanced Placement CS teachers. APCS has an annual conference. The lists are managed by the [APCS Community](https://apcommunity.collegeboard.org). Note that there are two different groups here, one for *APCS A* and one for *APCS Principles*. These are the two courses for which they provide testing.
- [CSTA](http://www.csteachers.org) This group is primarily for Educators at Secondary level and below, though many college faculty also belong. CSTA has an annual conference.

More (TBD)

Comment: Are there others?

Comment: Do you want people to reply to these questions? Why are they on meta and not the main site?

Comment: Actually, I'm hoping to have (here in meta) a common resource of things that answers on the main site can refer to without repeating the information.