# Development Environments used in Education

Tags: discussion, resource

This post is experimental and may disappear. It is in progress and will change

## Development Environments useful for educators

### Java

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) is a full featured development environment. It is open source. It is a plugin based workbench into which you can put a variety of tools for different purposes. In particular, you can use it as an IDE tailored for most modern languages.
- [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org) is in many ways similar to Eclipse.
- [Greenfoot](http://greenfoot.org) is a development environment for Java beginners. Among other useful things it has an active user community: [The Greenroom](http://greenroom.greenfoot.org). The two sites publish a large number of educational frameworks for use with the IDE.
- [BlueJ](http://bluej.org) is a Java IDE designed for education. It is a bit more advanced than Greenfoot. It, too, has a user community: [The Blueroom](http://blueroom.bluej.org).  The two sites publish a large number of educational frameworks for use with the IDE.
- [Alice](http://www.alice.org) is a 3D graphics educational environment for programming in Java.
- Scratch and Snap

### Python

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) can be made to work with Python.
- A [list of python environments](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) maintained by python.org

### Scheme

- [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/) A full featured Scheme environment. Racket is a Scheme dialect.

other

Note - information needed on each of these, including links TBD